# Linear Algebra- Find the matrix that represents the composite Linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am stuck on the following question,

Find the matrix that represents the composite function $GTS$ where

$S(x,y,z) = (2x,y+z)$, $T(x,y) = (2x + y, x + y, x-y)$, $G(x,y,z) = (y,x,x,z)$

Comment: What do you know about matrices? If you are very familiar with them, then Quintic's answer should be enough, but if not, you may need more help.

Comment: I know a little bit, probably enough to get it done!

Comment: Great good luck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HInt:** $GTS(x,y,z)=(2x+y+z,4x+y+z,4x+y+z,2x-y-z)$

Comment: Hey thanks dude for the hint! Gonna try to take it from here.

Comment: welcome :) @JonRoy

Comment: Is the (4x+y+z) supposed to be there twice?

Comment: Yes because $G(x,y,z)=(y,x,x,z)$ so $x$ is twice there.